# Suggestions for making a reusable try/catch block in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I have a class that has about 20-some methods in it. Each one does some web service message processing. I just had to make a change to it, and realized that every one of these methods has the exact same try/catch around it:

```
try
{
    /* *** actual processing specific to each method goes here *** */
}
catch (FaultException<CustomException> cfex)
{
    // common stuff
}
catch (CustomException cfex)
{
    // common stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // common stuff
}
finally
{
    FinalizeServiceCall(wsBus, wsMessage, response, logProps);
}
```

My question is; instead of having this exact same try/catch block in every method, is there a way to make it common? My thoughts were that .NET has stuff like `TransactionScope` that somehow detects if an exception occurs when leaving that block. Is there I was I can leverage something like that to make a common try/catch block? Any other ideas?

Comment: `TransactionScope` probably looks, in its `Dispose()` method, if `Complete()` was called (my guess is that `Complete()` sets a flag to `true`, and that `Dipose()` either commits if it's `true`, or rollbacks if otherwise).

Comment: Why not just move the try/catch logic *up* a level?

Comment: @Cody - I thought about moving it up a level, but each of these methods is a WCF [OperationContract] service method, so there isn't really a higher level, unless I create one.

Comment: @Etienne - You are correct, it checks the the Complete method in the Dispose. I knew that, but completely forgot when I asked the question :)

Comment: Why would your WCF implementation be *catching* fault exceptions?

Comment: @Kirk - In my case they happen to be a 'middle man' set of services. A client (external 3rd party) sends a message to this service (on a web server in the DMZ), and it in turn uses WCF to query an internal (on the LAN) application server that houses the business logic. So these WCF services are also clients to another set of services. Regardless, the question was not WCF specific. just looking for a good way to reusably handle the same sets of exceptions over and over.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Create a method that contains the try/catch and pass an `Action` into it and execute that action inside the try part:

```
public void Method1()
{
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // actual processing of Method 1
    };
    SafeExecutor(action);
}

public void Method1b()
{
    SafeExecutor(() =>
    {
        // actual processing of Method 1
    });
}

public void Method2(int someParameter)
{
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // actual processing of Method 2 with supplied parameter
        if(someParameter == 1)
        ...
    };
    SafeExecutor(action);
}

public int Method3(int someParameter)
{
    Func<int> action = () =>
    {
        // actual processing of Method 3 with supplied parameter
        if(someParameter == 1)
            return 10;
        return 0;
    };
    return SafeExecutor(action);
}

private void SafeExecutor(Action action)
{
    SafeExecutor(() => { action(); return 0; });
}

private T SafeExecutor<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (FaultException<CustomException> cfex)
    {
        // common stuff
    }
    catch (CustomException cfex)
    {
        // common stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // common stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        FinalizeServiceCall(wsBus, wsMessage, response, logProps);
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

The two versions of `SafeExecutor` give you the possibility to handle methods with and without return types.
`Method1b` shows that you don't need the variable `action` in your methods, you can inline it, if you think that's more readable.

Comment: That's exactly what I was creating. Good stuff.

Comment: Slightly less verbose: `return SafeExecutor(() => { return 42 });`

Comment: `Action` can't return a value. If you want to return a value, you need to use `Func<T>`.

Comment: As Cody Gray commented, it would may just be simpler to move the try/catch up a level. What are you gaining by catching exceptions in each of these methods?

Comment: This is definitely along the lines of what I was thinking. I was going to basically implement this same thing, but I wanted to post it up here on SO to see if there was a generally better or more-accepted way of accomplishing it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for pointing that out. I now tested the code in LINQPad and fixed it so it actually compiles...

Comment: This is is fantastic.

Answer (score 8):

There are ways in which you can do it easily - firstly for me I have started using AOP in order to catch my exceptions. This would effectively turn your code:

```
try
{
    /* *** actual processing specific to each method goes here *** */
}
catch (FaultException<CustomException> cfex)
{
    // common stuff
}
catch (CustomException cfex)
{
    // common stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // common stuff
}
finally
{
    FinalizeServiceCall(wsBus, wsMessage, response, logProps);
}
```

into something like:

```
[HandleException(Exception, FaultException<CustomException>, "Error Getting Details")]
public MYType GetDetails(string parameter)
{
    //.... call to service
}
```

By using Postsharp - [details here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Improve-Exception-Handling-and-Caching-using-PostSharp.aspx)

alternatively there is a blog post by [Mark Rendle](http://twitter.com/markrendle) on [how to catch exceptions in a Functional Programming way](http://blog.markrendle.net/2011/02/06/ddd9-teaching-jon-skeet-c-and-fun-with-exceptions/) - I have not tried this one though.

Comment: I definitely like the AOP approach, and that is probably what I would have done in a previous Java project that handled AOP better. In my particular case for this project, I am not using Postsharp, but still +1 for a very good answer.

Comment: Are there any good alternatives to PostSharp where I can create a similar 'HandleException' attribute to catch my exceptions? I've looked at a few alternatives, but it seemed like the other frameworks were more hassle than they were worth.

Answer (score 5):

You've identified a *cross-cutting concern*. You could employ an aspect-oriented programming (AOP) approach to this problem. This can either be performed at runtime by using a proxy that sits in front of your class or during compilation by using an AOP tool that modifies the compiled code.

In the past I've made use of [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) to do this (at runtime). Alternatively you could use one of the other AOP frameworks such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp).

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you done this with Castle Dynamic Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters are same or close to the same you can always pass in a delegate.  If they are not your could call the code by reflection and take a parameter of 'object[]' to pass to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write the above code in a method that takes a Action or a Func as a parameter which determines the method that should be called in the throw block, along with its parameters.

So that if you would call `M(1, "string")` in your throw block, it becomes `DoStuff(M, 1, "string")`

DoStuff would look like

```
void DoStuff<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> myMethod, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
        try
        {
            myMethod(arg1, arg2)
        }
        catch (FaultException<CustomException> cfex)
        {
            // common stuff
        }
        catch (CustomException cfex)
        {
            // common stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // common stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            FinalizeServiceCall(wsBus, wsMessage, response, logProps);
        }
}
```