# Catch-all error handling on application level?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form with a couple of buttons, and for each button I have error handling code:

```
try {bla bla} 
catch(Exception e){
  more bla
}
```

Is there any way I can set something up on the application level or something that will just catch all uncaught errors and display some generic message/ log the error? Now I have to create handling for every button so the code doesn't crash. It's an internal app so just displaying the message from whatever was thrown down there will suffice. After that the app would just wait for the next button click, so it wouldn't have to do anything afterwards.

There so much repetive code right now, wondering if there is some way to consolidate that and only deal with cases where there is a specific way to handle a specific error.

Regards Gert-Jan

Comment: If I were you I would try and fix the cause of all those exceptions first.

Comment: Windows forms, web app, what kind of app is this?

Comment: Beside fixing all those exceptions, I would like to to read about `Generics` that can lead you to reduce boiler-plate coding in your application and last but not the least, you can register for App Domain level error handler to handle all exceptions.

Comment: @Furqan do you have a link for that maybe?

Comment: @Joe It's mostly stupid stuff like clicking 'go' before specifying a outfile, stuff like that. It internal so I really don;t want to go down storyboard etc etc. If something goes wrong, just not crash without having to write all these different handlers.

Comment: @gjvdkamp: See my answer for a solution

Comment: @gjvdkamp - it's arguable as to whether that should raise an exception. For that kind of stateful thing, I would have a 'state transition' exception (i.e. you went from A to B when you should not have), but it should be balanced with code that actually prevents that from happening (i.e. if a user should not go from A -> B, don't allow them to do it).

Comment: @Joe, after those errors, nothing is left in an inconsistent state or anything. I could of course take the time to think about every error but frankly I don;t have the time and the added value of that would be very small. Just not crash and tell what went wrong is fine, looking for a way to do that centrally without having to redo it over and over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities:

1. [Suggestions for making a reusable try/catch block in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046382/suggestions-for-making-a-reusable-try-catch-block-in-c/6046452#6046452)
2. If you have a Winforms application, subscribe to the events [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) and [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx): http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/
3. If you have a WPF application, subscribe to [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) and [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. It catches the error, but is there any way to stop the code after that? Now it will still crash after the error is caught.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Otherwise, this event would be useless. There must be some error in your code. Have a look at the provided links.

Comment: It is though, what's the equivalent of ThreadException on WPF, do you know? Maybe I should catch that too.

Comment: Use [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: I can only find the System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException will that really work for a WPF application?

Comment: @phq: I don't think so. You should be able to use [the second one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: Try e.Handled=true in DispatcherUnhandledException

Answer (score 2):

Add this to you `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Exception currentException = Server.GetLastError();

    // your handling code goes here ...

    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: It has been a while since I did this kind of thing but... that doesn't feel very thread-safe.

Comment: Hi sorry it's a WPF app, didn;t mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) to accomplish this. Ideally, this happens when bootstrapping your application. You can find the AppDomain you're executing in via `AppDomain.Current`.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CatchAllHandler;That's it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your platform. In a web application you can bind the `Application_Error` event in Global Asax. In WCF you can inject an error handler of type [`System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) into the WCF stack, in forms applications you can bind the [`ThreadException`](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/top-level-exception-handling-in-windows-forms-applications-part-1/) event.

Using it may imho be a good idea in some situations since you prevent showing exception details to the user, but also indicates a certain slobbyness regarding exception handling. I have used WCF error handlers to convert domain exceptions to http status code which is simple. Whether it is a good practice or not I do not know. For asp.net applications it is also worth looking at [`elmah`](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) available via `NuGet`.

It is also possible to write a simple exception handler that allows you to repeat the try/catch blocks by sending reoutines as `Func` or `Action` like this

```
    var eh = new ExceptionHandler();

    eh.Process ( () => throw new SillyException());
```

with class `ExceptionHandler`

```
    class ExceptionHandler 
    { 
        public T Process(Func<T> func()) 
        {
           try { return func(); }
           catch(Exception ex) { // Do stuff }
        }

        public void Process(Action a) 
        { 
            try { action() }
            catch(Exception ex) { // Do stuff }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

If it is a WinForms app, you can encapsulate the Application.Run() call in a try catch statement, although I really wouldn't recommend this, you should only be using try catches where they are absoloutely needed and deal with exceptions whereever possible before just relying on catches.

I know this method works though as I had to use it temporarily once to do some cleaning up on the crashing of an application.

Comment: -1: This won't work, because afterwards the application won't work anymore.

Comment: This is true, but this is why I said I don't really recommend doing it. It just acts as a generic catch all, but it's really a lazy shabby way of doing it.