# WPF Application crashes on Win Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run my WPF application on Win Server 2008 R2 with .net 4.0 extended and client profile installed on it, but it crashes with the message that "Application Has Stopped Working" and no other info is shown.

My WPF application is 32-bit and targets .net 4.0, it runs fine on Win 7 32/64 bit systems.
I ran the Dependency Walker on Win Server and it shows that the following DLL's are missing:

- GPSVS.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL
- MF.DLL
- MFPLAT.DLL
- MFREADWRITE.DLL
- WLANAPI.DLL

GPSVS.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL are also missing on my system. I looked on google and i am not sure if these missing DLL's are the reason for the application crash.

Comment: You can use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (aka FusionLog) to check wether missing assemblies are your problem [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you had a look into the event viewer? Are you catching [unhandled exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6519029/572644)?

Comment: Yes i am catching the unhandled exceptions and its says "Unhadled Exception in App.xaml.cs"

Comment: What is the Exception/InnerException? Those DLLs you referenced are delay loaded and thus not likely your problem. We need more information about the exception.

Comment: I have solved the issue by installing the .Net Framework 3.5 on the Win Server 2008 R2.
At the moment the application is running fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by installing the .Net Framework 3.5 on the Win Server 2008 R2 by using the help from [here](http://randomtype.ca/blog/my-wpf-app-wont-run-on-windows-server-2008/)
At the moment the application is running fine.
It seems .Net Framework 3.5 has some stuff required by WPF and .Net Framework 4.0 does not install it.

Answer (score 0):

One additional tip which helped resolve WLANAPI.dll for me: Add the "Wireless Networking" feature from the Server Manager.