# Try-Catch not catching exception in method in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, try-catch

I have a search box and button combo in a WPF desktop application.  On clicking the search button, it uses a Predicate in the `Library.Find()` method to search for the precise search term entered.  This is all inside of a try-catch block, so that if the search term isn't matched it won't crash the application.

The problem is that the exception isn't caught, rather it still crashes despite the try-catch block.  Through debugging, I know the type of the exception is a `NullReferenceException`.  I've also tried catching `ArgumentNullException`, as this is the type listed for the `Library.Find()` method, and I've even tried using just a generic `Exception` type, but nothing is ever caught.  Can someone please help explain this?  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but none of the answers I looked at hada similar situation.

Note:  I don't have a try-catch block around the contents of the `ShowRecord()` method as this method is also used for record navigation buttons (i.e. Next Record, Prev Record, etc), and the `ArgumentNull` or `NullReference` don't make sense in that case.  I only have the try-catch around the code that could potentially throw the relevant error, as I was always taught.

**searchButton Code:**

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ShowRecord(gameLibrary.Find(x => x.GameName == searchBox.Text));
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        string term = searchBox.Text;
        searchBox.Text = "'" + term + "' was not found in the library.  Please try another search term.";
    }
}
```

**ShowRecord() Code:**

```
public void ShowRecord(Game game)
{
    titleBlock.Text = game.GameName;
    systemBlock.Text = game.GameSystem;
    formatBlock.Text = game.GameFormat;
    completedBlock.Text = game.IsComplete.ToYesNo();
    totalledBlock.Text = game.IsTotaled.ToYesNo();
    gamepassBlock.Text = game.GamePassStatus;
    installedBlock.Text = game.IsInstalled.ToYesNo();

    recordNumber.Content = (gameLibrary.FindIndex(x => x == game) + 1).ToString();
    recordCount.Content = gameLibrary.Count;
}
```

**EDIT**
I was pasting the stack trace as requested in one of the comments, and may have figured out the issue in doing so.  As stated in the initial question, the `ShowRecord()` method is also used for record navigation; as such, there is a segment in it where the TextBoxes are assigned the values for the located record (i.e. `TextBox.Text = gameLibrary.GameName`).  It's at this point that the exception is occurring, so even though it's happening within the `ShowRecord()` call in the button click event, the issue is actually not related to the `List.Find(Predicate)` part that the exceptions were supposed to catch.  Does this make sense?  To add to this, @Tam Bui mentioned adding a second catch block with only `Exception` being caught, and adding a breakpoint inside this:  I did this, and it still didn't stop at the breakpoint, it stopped at the TextBox value assignment.

Assuming this is the cause, thanks to everyone for the help.  I saw the exception not being caught by the generic `Exception`, and the impossibility of that blocked out all other reasoning for me, hence the confusion and missing where the actual break occurred.

Comment: Instead of trying to catch a `NullReferenceException` you should actually fix your code so it doesn't throw.

Comment: That's my plan eventually, but this is really my first attempt at using Predicates, so this is a learning step.  In fact this was only supposed to be an interim compile before moving on to adding the ability to search for partial matches, but I'd like to understand why this is happening as well, for educational benefit.

Comment: Something is not as you describe, if `Exception` isn't catching the exception then there is missing information in this question. Paste the actual stack trace

Comment: If you're trying to debug why this is happening, you should temporarily add a second "catch" statement after your `catch (ArgumentNullException ex)` that is `catch (Exception ex)` and then place a breakpoint in that second catch statement.  Then, in your Watch window, find out what `ex.GetType()` returns.  THAT is the exception you should be catching.  That's how I would debug this problem.

Comment: Are you switching thread contexts? The code you show is accessing the ui controls, so that is the UI thread. Where is gameLibrary, Game, ShowRecord? If an exception is thrown on a non-UI thread, it will not be marshalled back to the ui context. You would need to [set some top level Application UnhandledException handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6519029/458354) in the startup code.

Comment: Switch on "First-Chance Exception" debugging option

Comment: I may have found the cause, added it in an edit.  In case it's not the reason though, I wanted to mention that there is no multithreading right now (@mdisibio), and the 2nd catch with Exception and breakpoint didn't even allow the breakpoint to be reached (@Tam Bui).